# IIS Express unable to create the virtual directory

Tags: iis-express

I'm using IIS Express to create a virtual directory at `http://localhost:5000/` and received this error:

> Unable to create the virtual directory. The URL `http://localhost:5000/` is already mapped to a different folder...

This is because I've used the port 5000 for an old project before and it's no longer needed.

My question is, how can I remove the old mapping using IIS Express so I can create the virtual directory at the same port again?

Thanks

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this in one of two ways.

- You can remove the old project, or change its port using [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), which has an administration interface for IIS Express.
- You can also do it by hand, by modifying the `applicationhost.config` file directly. The file is located in the `%userprofile%\documents\IISexpress\config` folder. You can find the project configuration under the `<system.applicationHost>/<sites>` element.

**UPDATE:**
WebMatrix has been discontinued and support has officially [ended](https://blogs.iis.net/webmatrix/webmatrix-product-support-ends-on-november-1st-2017).

Comment: I also had to delete the site folder underneath  %userprofile%\documents\my web sites\ before I was able to reuse the port number.

Comment: Also, if running as administrator, be sure to check Users\\[admin acct name]\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

Comment: **1-** I've created a virtual directory (VD) using IIS. **2-** Added the VD name to the host file in `drivers -> etc`. **3-** Changed the settings in `<sites>` portion of `applicationHost.config` file. I'm still unable to run my application. On going to `Project -> Properties -> Web` and replacing the project url with my VD following alert is generated: `Local IIS Express URL:*something* specified for Web Project *someProject* has not been configured. To keep these settings u need to configure the VD. Would u like to create the VD now?`.

Comment: How should I be able to set my VD path as the default project URL so that on hitting `F5` the browser should show: `myPath.com`?

Answer (score 4):

No software installation required. Simply follow the steps:

Right-click the project node in the solution explorer and select the option to edit the project (.csproj) file. Near the bottom of the file, find the following:

`<iisurl></iisurl>`

Edit this entry to add your virtual directory:

`<iisurl>http://localhost:5000/</iisurl>`

Comment: This might have worked for you but it's also possible you will break the proj file such that the project won't load into Visual Studio [2012 in my case], especially if you modify an existing entry.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because I had a site on the IIS Server (not express) with the same bindings (domain name and port) as IIS Express was trying to use.

I thought that since the site was not started it would ignore it, but I was wrong. Once I change it in IIS, then the IIS Express one worked and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to run Visual Studio with administrative rights if you want to create Virtual directory on ports below 1024.