# Debugging ASP .NET MVC via modified 127.0.0.1 hostname?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localhost, iis-express

I'm facing an issue here.

For Facebook debugging reasons, I made a host entry in my hosts file which looks like this:

127.0.0.1 local.fablelane.com

**The error**

Now, when I try to load the IIS Express server, I get an error 400 (Bad Request), which looks like this in Chrome.

[image: Chrome error]

**Settings**

My Visual Studio 11 settings are as follows.

[image: Visual Studio settings]

**Edit 1**

It should be noted that when I enter "localhost:2000" in the browser, it works just fine.

**Edit 2**

If I change the project URL to "http://local.fablelane.com:2000/", the following error-message pops up. I am running Visual Studio 11 as an administrator by the way.

[image]

Comment: try to bind it via IIS, it always better than cassini

Comment: How do I do this? Can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Apologies for the answer, I deleted it. For some reason I totally missed that part about the host file. Does it work when you change from Local IIS to Dev Server? It did for me when I tried on my MVC project

Comment: That's okay. Sorry for the downvote. Local IIS is not an option for me I'm afraid - it lacks important features that I need in my web app.

Comment: IIS lacks features that you need in your web app ? Seeing how pretty much every single ASP.NET site in production (outside of those hosted on Mono) are being served by IIS, what exactly is this feature of which you speak?

Comment: Custom HTTP handlers, access to launching processes on the target server, and much more.

Comment: I'm quite sure all that can be done with IIS :-) Out of curiosity, what webserver software are you using to host your ASP.NET app then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that your site listens on the IP 127.0.0.1, but only for hostname 'localhost'.

You can set your 'Project Url' to 'http://local.fablelane.com:2000'. Also, I see no reason for 'Override application root URL' to be checked.

Or you could host in IIS instead of IIS Express and bind several hostnames for this site (so both localhost and local.fablelane.com would work). You can find more information about that [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: When I try to change the project URL I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/kTpld.png

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the port is already in use, since you added localhost:2000 earlier. IIS Express is a bit backwards like that. Try changing the port number, or, if that's not an option, remove the previous site binding. The accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608976/iis-express-unable-to-create-the-virtual-directory) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, use iss manager to publish your website locally. In the binding section add binding like you posted earlier local.fablelane.com.
Don't forget to check it in hosts file.
That should work.