# Getting error while creating virtual directory through visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Getting this error while creating virtual directory through visual studio 2012

"Unable to create the virtual directory. The URL'http:..localhost:80' is already
 mapped to a different folder on an IIS Express Site."

Can anyone help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS Express unable to create the virtual directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608976/iis-express-unable-to-create-the-virtual-directory)

Comment: But mr Adrian Faciu i do not created first.
i am creating just first time.

Comment: Does anyone using this site have a contact at Microsoft. Maybe they could as them to log this as a bug. "already mapped to a different folder" is a useless message. Most PC have thousands of folders - "a different folder" does not really narrow it down :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch in VS Website properties -> Web -> Serviers -> from IIS Express to Local IIS

Answer (score 0):

This has been posted quite a while back and I guess that you have already found your solution...But for other people out there:

I was trying to create a virtual directory in VS2012 for my web service

```
http://localhost/mywebservice
```

and I was getting the same error as you: "unable to create the virtual directory. the url is   `http://localhost:80`already mapped to a different folder on an iis"

So I check the IIS to make sure that I hadn't already configured one with the name "mywebservice", and it wasn't configured, still I was getting the error.

**Solution:** I created "mywebservice" virtual directory in the IIS, which was successful, then deleted it, and created it again, this time via VS2012 and voila! all happy now