# IIS Express fails to create virtual directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a web project that uses IISExpress and when attempting to load the project I receive the exception message below.

[image]

Comment: 1) Does [How can i change IIS Express port for a site](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21202917/1115360) help? 2) If you're ultimately going to deploy on IIS and you can run that on your computer, I suggest using IIS for development.

Comment: Using IIS is an option, but will be problematic when doing checkins that involve the.csproj files. For this reason, I would rather use IIS Express for development

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20723427/5292301

Comment: You can find answer on [iis-express-unable-to-create-the-virtual-directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608976/iis-express-unable-to-create-the-virtual-directory) thread.

Comment: Have you tried Pravin's suggested link?

Comment: Consider doing this (for kicks & giggles). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170133/creating-a-virtual-directory-failed-with-the-error